# Impact of PRE-SQL and POST -SQL on Push Down Optmisation in IICS

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud, iics

I am trying to implement push down optimization (PDO) in the IICS mapping task.I also have a PRE SQL in the source side.

I would like to know how this will impact when i execute the mapping task.

When i added PRE SQL in source and set push down optimization=FULL, I noticed the pre sql was not getting executed.

It would be great help if anyone can assist me on this. I checked online but could find any article connecting PRE/POST SQL with PDO.

Comment: This is odd. Something seems to be mising. I've never seen such case that Pre-SQL would be ignored by PDO. Further investigation / details needed. How can you tell it's messing? Can you share logs?